# Site is broken on WinXP+IE7

Tags: bug, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet Explorer 7 Support?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/663/internet-explorer-7-support)

Askubuntu.com looks odd on my work machine with WinXP and IE7: The header bar contains only the `@` icon but all the rest (username etc.) is gone, and hovering over their positions doesn't offer anything clickable either.

**Observations:**

- On my home machines (Win7+Ffox, Win7+Chrome, iPhone+Safari), the same site work fine.
  This would indicate an IE7 issue.
- On my work machine (WinXP+IE7), other SE sites work fine.
  This would indicate that the issue is only for Askubuntu, not all SE sites.
- On my work machine (WinXP+IE7), on any SE site, the toolbar function *insert an image from my computer* doesn't work (the *Browse* button is dead and the text field can't be clicked to manually enter the file path) - but this works fine on my home machines.
  This would indicate a general SE issue with IE7.

[image: missing information in top of screen]